# Detect offline and online clients realtime in Spring framework via Websocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I am building an app like slack.I've lots of clients running on both web and mobile.They connect to the websocket over `Stomp`.I want to detect which user is online and offline in realtime.`Websocket` server is running on `spring framework`.
spring accepts the requests as below.I set `heartbeat` `incoming` and `outgoing` values as `20000 ms`.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    public class WebSocketConfig  implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

        private List<StompPrincipal> onlineUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

            registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                    .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                    .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler())
                    .withSockJS();
        }

        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
            config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
            config.enableSimpleBroker("/ws")
                 .setTaskScheduler(new DefaultManagedTaskScheduler())
                 .setHeartbeatValue(new long[]{20000,20000});
        }
}
```

To determine which user requests to `Websocket`, I added a handshake handler as below.

```
class CustomHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {
         @Override
        protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                                          Map<String, Object> attributes) {

       String username=(String)attributes.get("name");
       StompPrincipal user = new StompPrincipal(username)

             onlineUsers.add(user);
            return user;
        }
    }

    class StompPrincipal implements Principal {
        String name;

        StompPrincipal(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

As the code above, I can see user is added the `onlineUser`, after he request `websocket server`.
But the problem is, I can not determine if the user is offline after being online.Can you please suggest me to determine this.
Also determining online and offline users by this way is best practice? if not, waiting for your suggestions.many thanks for now.

Answer (score 1):

After more search, I found a solution described [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180925052846/http://www.sergialmar.com/2014/03/detect-websocket-connects-and-disconnects-in-spring-4/).I implemented `ApplicationListener<SessionDisconnectEvent>` and override the method below.

```
@Override
     public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {

     }
```

By this way, I can catch the which user is disconnected from websocket connection.
I am still waiting for your best practise suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.SimpUserRegistry;`

inject it on your controller or service

```
@Autowired
SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry;
```

then create your logic in method in which you can invoke `simpUserRegistry.findSubscriptions(matcher)` like so:

```
public Set<SimpSubscription> onlineUsers(String chatroomId) {
        if(null == chatroomId || StringUtils.isEmpty(chatroomId)) {
            return findSubscriptions("");
        }
        Set<SimpSubscription> subscriptions = new HashSet<>();
        List<String> list = chatRoomService.listUserIdsInChatRoom(chatroomId);
        for (String userId: list) {
            subscriptions.addAll(findSubscriptions(userId));
        }
        return subscriptions;
    }
    
public Set<SimpSubscription> findSubscriptions(String userId) {
            return simpUserRegistry.findSubscriptions(new SimpSubscriptionMatcher() {
                @Override
                public boolean match(SimpSubscription subscription) {
                    return StringUtils.isEmpty(userId) ? true : subscription.getDestination().contains(userId);
                }
            });
        }
```

What this actually does, it gets all online users and match them with your specific userIds and if the chatroomId is empty, it will get you all the online users on all chatrooms.

Answer (score 0):

### Use the session Id to detect user

SocketJS

```
this.client = over(new SockJS(environment.SOCKET+'/end'));
this.client.connect({userId:'UserIdHere'}, () => {
});
```

Spring Boot

```
@Component
public class WebSocketEventListener {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketEventListener.class);

@Autowired
private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

@EventListener
public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectedEvent event) {

    StompHeaderAccessor stompAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    GenericMessage connectHeader = (GenericMessage) stompAccessor
            .getHeader(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.CONNECT_MESSAGE_HEADER); // FIXME find a way to pass the username
                                                                            // to the server
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, List<String>> nativeHeaders = (Map<String, List<String>>) connectHeader.getHeaders()
            .get(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS);

    String login = nativeHeaders.get("userId").get(0);
    String sessionId = stompAccessor.getSessionId();

    logger.info("Chat connection by user <{}> with sessionId <{}>", login, sessionId);

}

@EventListener
public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
    StompHeaderAccessor stompAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
    String sessionId = stompAccessor.getSessionId();
    logger.info("Chat connection by user <{}> with sessionId <{}>", "Nop", sessionId);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the spec under section
**20.4.12 Listening To ApplicationContext Events and Intercepting Messages**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-appplication-context-events

- `SessionConnectedEvent` — published shortly after a SessionConnectEvent when the broker has sent a STOMP CONNECTED frame in response to the CONNECT. At this point the STOMP session can be considered fully established.
- `SessionDisconnectEvent` — published when a STOMP session ends. The DISCONNECT may have been sent from the client or it may also be automatically generated when the WebSocket session is closed. In some cases this event may be published more than once per session. Components should be idempotent to multiple disconnect events.

You can store online users in a cache if you need it, and stream the online status of relevant users over the websocket to the client as they come and go.